# Afnetworking delegate methods not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code please check where i was wrong. NO success or failure methods will be called after taking request. Please help me on this.

```
-(void)downLoadTask {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString*  mediaKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Sample.m4v", documentsDirectory];
    NSLog(@"%@",mediaKey);
    NSString *strPath = @"/sites/default/files/media/Master_Talara1_9.mp4";

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[self.HTTPClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:strPath parameters:nil]];

    operation.downloadSpeedMeasure.active = YES;

    [operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"time out");
        // Clean up anything that needs to be handled if the request times out
        // It may be useful to initially check whether the operation finished or was cancelled
    }];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:mediaKey append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        humanReadableRemaingTime = [operation.downloadSpeedMeasure humanReadableRemainingTimeOfTotalSize:totalBytesExpectedToRead numberOfCompletedBytes:bytesRead];

        NSLog(@"Time is human read %@",humanReadableRemaingTime);           
    }];       
}
```

Is there any few methods to be implemnted to get call AFNetWorking delegate methods

Comment: Do you add the operation to some queue to run it?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write code to start download task at the end of function.

```
[operation start];
```